# Where can be use onSaveInstanceState where parameters are passed different Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

For Acitivity there is already a method called onSaveInstacestate(Bundle) which used to store the data of activity which is overridden method.

As i see, there are two different onSaveInstanceState where parameters are passed differently as below.

```
@Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState)
    {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState);
        Log.i("test", "onSaveInstanceState called **********");
    }
```

and

```
@Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
    {
         super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
          Log.i("test", "onSaveInstanceState with bundle only called");
    }
```

So, at what circumstances this two methods can be use? 
please describe in detail.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From API Level 21, `onSaveInstanceState()`has a new parameter called that takes object of `PersistableBundle`. You can read more about PersistableBundle on [Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PersistableBundle.html)

In short,

For API 21 and above

```
@Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState)
    {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState);
        Log.i("test", "onSaveInstanceState called **********");
    }
```

For API less than 20

```
@Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
    {
         super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
          Log.i("test", "onSaveInstanceState with bundle only called");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Onkar.
I read the document.. but need to see how can be use this PersistableBundle in onSaveInstancestate and onRestoreInstace state ?

Comment: ...and for compatibility between versions?

Answer (score 25):

This deserves an expanded answer. As the accepted answer states, since API level 21 there's an additional overload for `onSaveInstanteState`.

Available since API level 1 ([Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle))):

`void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState)`

Addition introduced with API level 21 ([Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle,%20android.os.PersistableBundle))):

`void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState)`

The latter one with the `PersistableBundle` is not a replacement of the former one. It is only used when the `Activity` attribute [`R.attr.persistableMode`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr#persistableMode) is set to as `persistAcrossReboots`. When such an `Activity` is going to be persisted, `onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState)` will be called and you receive a `PersistableBundle` to store your instance state.

To restore the state of an `Activity` with [`R.attr.persistableMode`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr#persistableMode) set to as `persistAcrossReboots`, there's

`void onRestoreInstanceState (Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState)`

Be aware that `onRestoreInstanceState (Bundle savedInstanceState)` is not called if the one with the `PersistableBundle` is called. I assume the same is true for `onSaveInstanceState`, but I haven't checked it and the docs do not mention it at the time of API level 28.

There's also an appropriate overload for [`onCreate()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle,%20android.os.PersistableBundle)).

Comment: This make sense. The accepted answer is misleading, you can't use the new one in higher api blindly.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say anything more than what is said but this some helping code to help you
I do this in base activity to make sure my data is always saved

```
public abstract void saveInstanceState(Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState);

@Override
public final void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState) {
    saveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState);
}

@Override
protected final void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
    saveInstanceState(outState, null);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

I'm using final keyword so i don't forget and override one of the methods 
instead of my custom abstract one